# How do I structure a notification key request to GCM Cloud Connection Server (XMPP)?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to create a user notification key to group device notification by user. This topic is written about in the [GCM documentation on User Notifications](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html).

The GCM documentation claims to support notification key requests for both XMPP and HTTP connections, but does not give any examples regarding the structure of an XMPP message.

I am now attempting to request a notification key. I've used the information provided in the documentation and have structured my request message as such:

```
<message id="XK4EG-6"><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{"operation":"create","notification_key_name":"appUser-Chris","registration_ids":["4","8","15"]}</gcm></message>
```

I receive the following error from GCM:

```
<message id="XK4EG-6" type="error" to="I REMOVED THIS"><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{"operation":"create","notification_key_name":"appUser-Chris","registration_ids":["4","8","15"]}</gcm><error code="400" type="modify"><bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">InvalidJson: JSON_PARSING_ERROR : Missing Required Field: message_id</text></error></message>
```

I haven't been getting this sort of error with any of my previous messages to GCM, so I'm not sure how to handle it. It seems that I'm missing a message ID, but this is not required for notification key requests. Has anybody handled this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem therefore I have been studying the issue for a few hours and here is the conclusion.

You are missing the *"message_id":* parameter in the JSON payload, it's a required parameter in CCS!:

> ***message_id***: In CCS, uniquely identifies a message in an XMPP connection. The value is a string that uniquely identifies the associated message. The value is a string. **Required**.

Note that in the  [GCM documentation on User Notifications](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html) topic *"message_id":* isn't included because use HTTP connection server.

Moreover, note that in XMPP *"registration_ids":* parameter doesn't exists in XMPP implementation, you should use *"to":* parameter instead and it only allow you to pass one registration id per message. In XMPP the value for *"to":* parameter is a string, not an array of strings:

> ***to:*** In CCS, used in place of registration_ids to specify the recipient of a message. Its value must be a registration ID. **The value is a string. Required.**

Now, you should have something like this:

```
// This is code for a python xmpp server version
send_queue.append({"operation": "create",
                  "message_id": random_id(),
                  "to": REGISTRATION_ID,
                  "notification_key_name": "appUser-User1"})
```

But this only return me an ACK. I expect a *notification_key* but I receive only an ACK, I don't know why.

Server log:

- sent message from server:

  ```
  <message id="3"><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{to: I REMOVED THE ID, operation: create, notification_key_name: appUser-User1, message_id: 5xEYEIHZ}</gcm></message>
  ```
- got message:

  ```
  <message><data:gcm xmlns:data="google:mobile:data">"message_id":"5xEYEIHZ","message_type":"ack","from":"I REMOVED THE ID"}</data:gcm></message>
  ```

  This is an ACK but not the register_key expected :(

### Conclusion

I think that obtain a notification key from XMPP server is not possible for now. Documentacion is not available and the methods that I tried returns an ACK but not the notification key.
For now, we only can use the HTTP method, which works fine, I do a test from a linux console:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=YOUR_KEY" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "project_id:YOUR_PROJECT_ID" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"operation\":\"create\",\"notification_key_name\":\"appUser-User\",\"registration_ids\":[\"YOUR_REGISTRATION_ID\"]}"
```

output:

```
{"multicast_id":7151337537866826426,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1406728451796338%921c249af9fd7ecd"}]}
```